# stripe.invoices.sendinvoice is not a function - Stripe Billing (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am implementing the following code for sending invoices to customers:
From https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/sending

```
stripe.invoices.sendInvoice(invoice.id, function(err, invoice) {
  // asynchronously called
});
```

However, I get this error message:

> TypeError: stripe.invoices.sendInvoice is not a function

What is the problem here? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely need to update your `stripe-node` dependency, as support for these invoice features was added quite recently.

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#6140---2018-11-09